# Flux- infinite scroll: i cannot think of how to stick to unidirectional data flow

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux

i am trying to implement an infinite scroll from many items that i get from the server, but i cannot find any proper way to keep the flux architecture design rules.

the idea is: on the first load, i get a full item list from server (only id's), then using ajax i fetch each time 20 more items.

**the list is kept in the Store, and also the loaded items. the view listens on loaded items and render them, when it reaches scroll bottom it calls an action which should then fetch 20 more items, and so on.**

**the problem is**: the Action should know what items to fetch, the unloaded items list is in the store, so it has to get it from the store directly, which is a "don't do it' in flux. other alternatives are to handle all the logic in the stores, which seems also a bad idea..

can anyone think of a nice solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: it is OK within unidirectional flow for a component to *read* directly from store (see below)

Make your action explicitly say which items to fetch: "Give me items 21-40 please".
This fires a) (async) ajax call to get items 21-40 and b) dispatch to the store.
The component knows a) which items it has already rendered, and b) which items the user wants to see next, so it can pass along the above action message without talking to the store again.

The store receives the request. The store knows it does not have the items yet. The component does not know yet.
Store emits change, and your component (assuming it is listening to store changes) gets current state from store. If the items weren't there, the store provides a loading state ("loading items 21-40" or similar). The component displays the loading state. (or, if the loaded items are already fully in store, it simply renders items 21-40).

As soon as items 21-40 are delivered by ajax return, your store updates with the full items 21-40. (if they happened to be in store already, no problem, no update). Store emits another change. Component hears this, and re-renders.

ASIDE:
Unidirectional flow is for updates:
Component -> lower components -> actions (-> webAPI -> action) -> dispatcher -> stores -> components

In unidirectional flow rules are:

1. Components are allowed to push data updates only to *lower* components (by passing new props, which trigger re-render), not to higher components
2. Components are allowed to maintain an internal state, which they can pass on as props to children (see 1)
3. Components are allowed to push data updates or update requests also to the dispatcher (in "actions"). The dispatcher then forwards the updates to the stores and/or to some server via eg webAPI.
4. Components are allowed to listen to store changes and pull/ read data directly from the store.
5. Stores listen to the dispatcher, and update if they receive news from the dispatcher.
6. Stores may also listen to other stores, and read data from other stores to update themselves
7. Stores emit change as soon as they have updated, so that any components listening can do something (typically read new data) (see 4.)
8. WebAPI results from the server are "actions". They go through dispatcher which informs the relevant stores to update. (See 5)

Unidirectional flow breaks if:

- Component actively fetches/ pulls data from a higher component - such data should be pushed by higher component as props (see 1)
- Component actively fetches data from child - as parent, component should already have this data. If it is in child's state, then state is designed at too low level.
- Component directly updates store - should be with an action through dispatcher

And also breaks if (although some disagree):

- Store directly updates another store - should be pull instead of push (see 6)
- Store pushes update through an action - only webAPI (see 8) and components (see 3) are allowed to issue actions
- Component directly does webAPI request and handles result in state - should go through dispatcher

Comment: But how will the action know what items to ask? It have to keep track on loaded items. So it becomes statefull.. Or it has to ask the store which items are already loaded.. And then unidirectional data flow concept is broken

Comment: The action is "give me items 21-40". It does not need to talk to store to formulate request. After unidirectional flow, the store says "I changed". Component reads store, and then learns if the items are there (render them), or not yet (display loading state). After that, the component can have a new action message ready with "give me 41-60", waiting for the user to hit the scroll/get next trigger in UI.

Comment: thanks a lot, for your detailed answer. i might not be getting it correctly, l look on this:
"Component actively fetches/ pulls data from a higher component - such data should be pushed by higher component as props (see 1)"

if the action pulls the data from the store, aint i violating this?

Comment: Store is not the same as component. Component fetching from store is OK. Component passing that data in action is also OK. Component fetching from higher (parent) component is Not OK. Action is different from store and component. Action should have all data it needs (given by component), to pass through dispatcher to store. So action should not actively fetch from store.